# Is there a way to enable outbox in MassTransit just for specific message types?

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a use case were I want to add outbox feature in MassTransit in some of my messages but not all.

In other words when i'm publishing using IPublishEndpoint to a message "UploadImage" I want to use outbox so I need to also commit changes to database. But, when I'am publishing to lets say "ImageDeleted" I don't want to use outbox I want to publish to the receive endoint directly to the message broker

I have followed the documentation of Masstransit and configured outbox and it is working. Sadly i didn't find a way to implement what I want to do.

Do I neet to implement multiBus for this? is there no other way?

Comment: From where are you producing the `ImageDeleted` event? In a consumer?

Comment: @ChrisPatterson from Controller not within a consumer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are within a consumer, and you want to skip the outbox for a specific message, you can use the following internal method:

```cs
var skipContext = InternalOutboxExtensions.SkipOutbox(context);

await skipContext.Publish(new ImageDeleted(...));
```

If you aren't within a consumer, can you use `IBus`?

Comment: Sadly i'm not within a consumer (:

Comment: yes I can use IBus